# Office Add-In icon does not show on Desktop Applications

Tags: office-js

I created a word Add-in using the Yeoman generator to create my add-in. My Add-In is working perfectly but I wanted to show the Icon of my Add-In on the toolbar. If I use office on the web the Icon shows without any issues. If I use the Word (2016)(version:16.0.4939) on the Desktop I can't get the Icon to display in none of the ribbons toolbar (Home, Insert, Design, Layout, References, etc ....).

This is part of the manifest.

```
 <!-- Control. It can be of type "Button" or "Menu". -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="TaskpaneButton">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <!-- ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource. -->
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                    <!-- ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource. -->
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                  </Icon>

                  <!-- This is what happens when the command is triggered (E.g. click on the Ribbon). Supported actions are ExecuteFunction or ShowTaskpane. -->
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
                    <!-- Provide a url resource id for the location that will be displayed on the task pane. -->
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
```

What I am missing? Does Word on the Desktop does not show the Icons? How can I show the Add-In icon on the desktop for easy user access?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are working with the perpetual license Word 2016. Add-in Commands are only supported in Outlook in perpetual license Office 2016. See [Add-in Commands Requirement Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/add-in-commands-requirement-sets).

Comment: The add-in is added to word and it opens it and works, but the icon is under the dropdown list of Insert > **My Add-ins** it is not added to the toolbar.

Comment: what options I have to display the icon on the ribbon toolbar ?

Comment: Can I edit the RibbonXML to launch an javascript add-in?